# What does "<D:" means in a function declaration?

Tags: swift

Feeling totally newbie on this, but I'm trying to create a UITABLEVIEW inside a UITABLEVIEW cell, and looking for examples on internet I found this Swift structure:

```
func setTableViewDataSourceDelegate<D:UITableViewDelegate & UITableViewDataSource>(_ dataSourceDelegate: D, forRow row: Int)
```

What does it mean? Tried to find the meaning of the "D:" stuff in the documentation but found nothing.

Comment: `D` is generic type that conforms to `UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

Comment: if you tilt your head right, `<D:` is a shocked face with long beard – because [generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) can be shockingly complex, and one can grow long beard before comprehend it.

Comment: We usually use "T" for generic (when there is only one), but here, "D" standing for "DataSource & Delegate" make sense, but anyway, that's just naming.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers!! Now I have a starting point! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [generic type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) definition. It means "any type 'D' that conforms to both `UITableViewDelegate` and  `UITableViewDataSource`"

And the argument `dataSourceDelegate` is declared to be of that type.

The angle brackets `<` and `>` enclose the generic type definition analogously to the parentheses `(` and `)` enclosing the arguments.